# Can not sign in to Azure from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2012

I am not able to login to my azure account from Visual Studio Professional 2012. I am getting an error shown below

[image]

However I am able to login to my Azure account using browser.

I have performed below steps

1) Opened Server Explorer in Visual Studio

2) Clicked on Microsoft Azure Subscription icon

3) Sign in Dialog Box opens up asking for my email, which I provided and clicked continue

4) Selected Microsoft Personal Account from the option provided

5) Entered Password clicked submit

[image]

6) Error dialog box opens up as shown earlier.

I feel that it is related to management certificate as I am also not able to run certain commands like Get-AzureDeployment from Azure PowerShell, whereas Get-AzureSubscription works fine.

I have already saved publishsettings file from Azure and there are certificates installed in Personal section in Certificate manager.

Comment: Do you have latest azure SDK and power shell?

Comment: Milen, I have Azure SDK 2.6 and Azure PowerShell 1.0.1

Comment: Yes, afaik SDK 2.8 (latest) is not available for VS2012 (only up to 2.6) but I cannot confirm that this is the issue here...

Comment: Also I get an error when I try to run Add-AzureAccount in powershell and supply my credentials "Add-AzureAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"

Comment: Oh,with latest powershell use `Add-AzureRmAccount`, have you tried that?

Comment: Also try `$myvar =  Add-AzureAccount `and see if can peek, what's in the inner exception

Comment: It gives below error                                                                                                    Add-AzureAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed 
unexpectedly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount

Comment: Even Add-AzureRmAccount gives the same error

Comment: I don't think I could help any further, too generic error message, could be anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. As I could see that Visual Studio and Power shell both were failing. Visual Studio was not able to connect to Azure and Power shell scripts where I was trying to add Azure Account failed. By doing a bit more searching and reading few article, I came to know that Visual Studio as well as Power shell scripts apart from using your credentials for azure also use management certificate to communicate with azure. A network tool used in our organization was causing issue in this https communication. Just got it enabled from IT team and I am done.